# logstash with hdfs for paritcular duration

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

Hi I am new logstash and i have done with read the data from tcp and write to the hdfs...that part is don but i want to write to data to 4 different folder of hdfs

Here is sample code

```
input {
tcp {

host => "X.X.X.X"
port => 5051
codec => json_lines
}

}
filter 
{
  mutate 
{
 remove_field => [ "@version", "path", "host","logger_name","tags","stack_info","level","port","type"]
 }
 mutate {
         add_field => { "count" => "1"} 
 }

 }

 output {
 webhdfs 
    {
    
        host => "127.0.0.1"                
        port => 50070  
        path => "/folder/%{+YYYY-MM-dd_HH-mm}.csv"          
        user => "hduser"                
        codec => line { format => "%{message}"} 
    }
```

here issue is i have write to folder  but later on i want to write to 3 more different folder like folder1,folder2,folder3 for certain duration of time....

Comment: Do you want to write the same event to there or do you want to make a decision to which one it has to go? If you want to do it all in parallel, just add extra webhdfs sections in your output {...}, if you want to choose, you could use a tag to decide which to take using if ("mytag" in [tags]) functionality or if possible to add the name of the folder to a value of a field (like you are using %{message} you could use %{foldername} or something like that to have a single webhdfs output

Comment: data will be different.. like for 1 minute 1 want to write a data to folder1 ..then next 1 minutes to folder2  and so on like this.. @YouryDW

Comment: Am I getting it right if you just need 60 folders then with the number of minutes that the event happened in, or is there another logic behind it? It still a bit vage of what the logic is to decide when to write to folder1, folder2... is it purely based on the time of event or you want to decide or is there some other logic that we need to be aware of?

Comment: i have a predefined 4 folders on hdfs....and i want to create csv per min. but need to dumpeed evenly in 4 folders.

like :
ex 
00:01 min => folder1
02:03 min => folder2
03:04 min => folder3
04:05 min => folder4
05:06 min => folder1....

in this cycle   @YouryDW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, you will need to use some `mutate` filters and some conditionals.

First you need to get the value of the minute from the `@timestamp` of the event and add the value into a new field, you can use the `[@metadata]` object, which can be use to filtering, but it will not be present in the output event.

```
mutate {
    add_field => { "[@metadata][minute]" => "%{+mm}" }
}
```

Then you will need to specify which minute will be saved in which folder.

For example, if you want something like this:

00:00 to 00:59 - folder1
01:00 to 01:59 - folder2
02:00 to 02:59 - folder3
03:00 to 03:59 - folder4

And start with folder1 in the next minute, 04:00 to 04:59, you will need something like this, considering just the first 8 minutes.

```
if [@metadata][minute] in ["00", "04"] {
    mutate {
        add_field => {"[@metadata][folder]" => "folder1" }
    }
}
if [@metadata][minute] in ["01", "05"] {
    mutate {
        add_field => {"[@metadata][folder]" => "folder2" }
    }
}
if [@metadata][minute] in ["02", "06"] {
    mutate {
       add_field => {"[@metadata][folder]" => "folder3" }
    }
}
if [@metadata][minute] in ["03", "07"] {
    mutate {
        add_field => {"[@metadata][folder]" => "folder4" }
    }
}
```

Then in your output you will use `[@metadata][folder]` in your path.

```
path => "/[@metadata][folder]/%{+YYYY-MM-dd_HH-mm}.csv"
```

You just need to expand the conditionals to the other minutes in the hour.

Comment: [2021-04-26T12:13:45,153][WARN ][logstash.outputs.webhdfs ][main] Failed to flush outgoing items {:outgoing_count=>83, :exception=>"WebHDFS::IOError", 
As per your suggestion i have the configuration still getting the error @leandrojmp

Comment: Were you getting this error before? You didn't mention it. Anyway, I don't think this is related to the configuration, it is an IO error, could be permissions on the file system or anything else. I suggest that you open another question and share the logs of the error, you probably have more error logs that explain better what happened.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @leandrojmp   i have a question can we create time duration dynamic ?